# Mathematica generated DAE file can not be opened by other softwares

Tags: export, mesh

I am building a 3D model in mathematica, but the exported dae file can not be opened other softwares except mathematica, ie., xcode and preview on mac.  As a comparison, the same dae file can be reimported to mathematica just as fine.  Don't know what to know.

Here is my code:

```
test = MeshRegion[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8}, {Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}], 
Polygon[{3, 2, 6, 7}], Polygon[{3, 4, 8, 7}], 
Polygon[{1, 2, 6, 5}], Polygon[{1, 4, 8, 5}]}]

Export["test.dae", test]
Import["test.dae"]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems most likely that Wolfram Support would have to look into this, rather than end users.